# Adjusting spaces for matrices

Tags: matrices, arrays

I can't adjust the spacing this awkward spacing between the row operation sign and the bottom two matrices. I would want to align the bottom two matrices to the left (right next to the row operation signs). I have tried using \setlength\mathindent{0}, but couldn't find a fix. Here's the picture and complete code [image: Here's]

```
    \documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\newenvironment{rowequmat}[1]{\left(\array{@{}#1@{}}}{\endarray\right)}
\newenvironment{redmatrix}
  {\left(\array{@{}rrr|c@{}}}
  {\endarray\right)}
\newenvironment{ropmatrix}
  {\array{@{}c@{}}}
  {\endarray}
\newcommand\opone[2]{\xrightarrow{(#1)\times r_#2}}
\newcommand\optwo[3]{\xrightarrow{r_#1{}+{} #2r_#3}}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\setlength\mathindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{5}
&
\huge{
\begin{redmatrix}
 -2 & -1 & 1 & c_1 - a\\
 -1 &  -2 & -1 & c_2 - a \\
 -1 &  -1 & -2 & c_3 - a \\
\end{redmatrix}} \\[\parskip]
&
\setlength\mathindent{0pt}
\huge{
\begin{ropmatrix}
\optwo{2}{}{3}
\end{ropmatrix}}
&
\huge{
\begin{redmatrix}
 -2 & -1 & -1 & c_1 - a \\
  0 &  -1 & 1 & c_2 - c_3 \\
  0 & -1  & -3 & 2c_3 - c_1 -a \\   
\end{redmatrix}}\\\\[\parskip]
\\
&
\huge{
\begin{ropmatrix}
\opone{1/3}{2}
\end{ropmatrix}}
&
\huge{
\begin{redmatrix}
-2 & -1 & -1 & c_1 - a \\
 0 & -1 & 1 & c_2 - c_3 \\
 0 & 0  & 4 & 3c_3 - c_2 - c_1 -a \\   
\end{redmatrix}}\\
\\
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Any help will be immensely appreciated.

Comment: `\huge{` size commands do not take an argument so there should be no `{` but also they can not be inside a math environment such as  `aligned`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What's the purpose of `rowequmat` here?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newenvironment{rowequmat}[1]{\left(\array{@{}#1@{}}}{\endarray\right)}
\newenvironment{redmatrix}
  {\left(\array{@{}rrr|c@{}}}
  {\endarray\right)}
% \newenvironment{ropmatrix}
%   {\array{@{}c@{}}}
%   {\endarray}
\newcommand\opone[2]{\xrightarrow{(#1)\times r_#2}}
\newcommand\optwo[3]{\xrightarrow{r_#1{}+{} #2r_#3}}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\setlength\mathindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
I'm wondering if you are looking for
\begin{align*}
\MoveEqLeft[5]{
\begin{redmatrix}
 -2 & -1 & 1 & c_1 - a\\
 -1 &  -2 & -1 & c_2 - a \\
 -1 &  -1 & -2 & c_3 - a \\
\end{redmatrix} }\\
\optwo{2}{}{3}
&
\begin{redmatrix}
 -2 & -1 & -1 & c_1 - a \\
  0 &  -1 & 1 & c_2 - c_3 \\
  0 & -1  & -3 & 2c_3 - c_1 -a \\   
\end{redmatrix}
\\
\opone{1/3}{2}
&
\begin{redmatrix}
-2 & -1 & -1 & c_1 - a \\
 0 & -1 & 1 & c_2 - c_3 \\
 0 & 0  & 4 & 3c_3 - c_2 - c_1 -a \\   
\end{redmatrix}
\end{align*}
or
\begin{align*}
&\begin{redmatrix}
 -2 & -1 & 1 & c_1 - a\\
 -1 &  -2 & -1 & c_2 - a \\
 -1 &  -1 & -2 & c_3 - a \\
\end{redmatrix} \\
\optwo{2}{}{3}
&
\begin{redmatrix}
 -2 & -1 & -1 & c_1 - a \\
  0 &  -1 & 1 & c_2 - c_3 \\
  0 & -1  & -3 & 2c_3 - c_1 -a \\   
\end{redmatrix}
\\
\opone{1/3}{2}
&
\begin{redmatrix}
-2 & -1 & -1 & c_1 - a \\
 0 & -1 & 1 & c_2 - c_3 \\
 0 & 0  & 4 & 3c_3 - c_2 - c_1 -a \\   
\end{redmatrix}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was looking for the second one. Thank you :)

Comment: @AsadRaza If the answer worked for you, could you perhaps accept it by clicking the check mark left of it?

Answer (score 1):

Albeit I don't see why you want a `\huge` fontsize, I propose one of these layouts, with a simplified code, and equal lengths arrows (with the `eqparbox` package). Note `\huge` is not a command which takes ann argument but a mere switch, and a matrix doesn't end with a `\\` (this adds an empty row).

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{array}
\newenvironment{rowequmat}[1]{\left(\array{@{}#1@{}}}{\endarray\right)}
\newenvironment{redmatrix}
  {\left(\array{@{}rrr|c@{}}}
  {\endarray\right)}
\newenvironment{ropmatrix}
  {\array{@{}c@{}}}
  {\endarray}
\newcommand\opone[2]{\xrightarrow{\eqmakebox[op]{$\, (#1)\times r_#2 $\,}}}
\newcommand\optwo[3]{\xrightarrow{\eqmakebox[op]{\,$ r_#1{}+{} #2r_#3 $\,}}}
\setlength\mathindent{0pt}

\begin{document}

{\huge
\begin{align*}
 & \begin{redmatrix}
 -2 & -1 & 1 & c_1 - a\\
 -1 & -2 & -1 & c_2 - a \\
 -1 & -1 & -2 & c_3 - a
\end{redmatrix} \\[0.7ex]
\optwo{2}{}{3}
&
\begin{redmatrix}
 -2 & -1 & -1 & c_1 - a \\
  0 & -1 & 1 & c_2 - c_3 \\
  0 & -1 & -3 & 2c_3 - c_1 -a
\end{redmatrix}\\[0.7ex]
\opone{1/3}{2}
&
\begin{redmatrix}
-2 & -1 & -1 & c_1 - a \\
 0 & -1 & 1 & c_2 - c_3 \\
 0 & 0 & 4 & 3c_3 - c_2 - c_1 -a
\end{redmatrix}
\end{align*}}

{\huge
\begin{flalign*}
 & \mathrlap{\begin{redmatrix}
 -2 & -1 & 1 & c_1 - a\\
 -1 & -2 & -1 & c_2 - a \\
 -1 & -1 & -2 & c_3 - a
\end{redmatrix}} & & \\[0.7ex]
 & \optwo{2}{}{3}
 \begin{redmatrix}
 -2 & -1 & -1 & c_1 - a \\
  0 & -1 & 1 & c_2 - c_3 \\
  0 & -1 & -3 & 2c_3 - c_1 -a
\end{redmatrix}
\\[0.7ex]
 & \opone{1/3}{2}
\begin{redmatrix}
-2 & -1 & -1 & c_1 - a \\
 0 & -1 & 1 & c_2 - c_3 \\
 0 & 0 & 4 & 3c_3 - c_2 - c_1 -a
\end{redmatrix}
\end{flalign*}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am a LateX novice and this is HUGE help. I, however, can't figure our a way to input a minus operation (say $R_2 -R_1$).